# XML Signing. Wrong Digital Signature

Tags: .net, xml

Have third party software, which signs XML, and its verified by some third party service.

Fiddler shows:

```
<ds:SignatureValue>
    Ds+gdisYg7C8ZdZqEXJNkhTLabsuWwUpUcdLNRn+qr6HhmHX01g0an6No59va6+AlaSZpcjw
    3oRh7sVpUaL/Yg==
</ds:SignatureValue>
```

And my signature with .net:

```
<ds:SignatureValue>
    Ds+gdisYg7C8ZdZqEXJNkhTLabsuWwUpUcdLNRn+qr6HhmHX01g0an6No59va6+AlaSZpcjw3oRh7sVpUaL/Yg==
</ds:SignatureValue>
```

And it can not be verified.
So, why does it matter how formated SignatureValue? Or it doesnt matter?

Comment: Is your signature method the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't matter. But many specifications that use Base64 encoding recommends limiting the line length to 64 (or 76), due to legacy reasons. XML signature implicitly recommends this because XML schema does. I'm sure the .net library can be instructed to split the line into 64 char pieces.

Comment: It's 72 character lenght. So how .net library can be instructed?